# Trim String in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have below string & want only state name in output, kindly suggest me.

```
'State - Rajasthan,Zone - Jaipur-I,Circle - Circle-P, Jaipur,Ward - Circle-P, jaipur - Ward-2'
```

Desired Output- Rajasthan

Comment: Will the State ALWAYS be present in the string?  Could the heading of `State - ` be there but no value entered? In other words does the data source ensure all data sources are present and correct?

Comment: Oh and could the state be in a different position then the first element in the list?

Answer (score 1):

According to that example, here are a few options you might consider:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'State - Rajasthan,Zone - Jaipur-I,Circle - Circle-P, Jaipur,Ward - Circle-P, jaipur - Ward-2'
  3     from dual
  4    )
  5  select substr(col, instr(col, ' ', 1, 2) + 1,
  6                     instr(col, ',') - instr(col, ' ', 1, 2) - 1
  7               ) state,
  8         --
  9         replace(substr(col, 1, instr(col, ',') - 1), 'State - ', '') state2,
 10         --
 11         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2) state3
 12  from test;

STATE     STATE2    STATE3
--------- --------- ---------
Rajasthan Rajasthan Rajasthan

SQL>
```